# Can i put a like button on a ad and serve it through dfp

Tags: javascript, google-dfp

I want to create an ad, probably java script, that will say "Like us on FB" and have the like button below it within the ad. The button will allow you to like our fb page without leaving the webpage. Can I serve this type of ad in dfp small business.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just use a custom creative and then put the facebook like button code inside it.

https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3162397?hl=en&ref_topic=28159